# Regex not working (lookaround problems)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So I've been using Stackoverflow for 4 years now each time I needed something clear and tidy.

Here is the case :
I have a text file with 2 columns separeted by a tab, the first columns is in a language (e.g. French) and the second is in English.

une ampoule \t lightbulb

I'd like to be able to match the \t depending on multiple factors, to replace it by \t and the proper article (a/an/the):

- to be relplaced by "\tan", needs to be on a line that starts with "un" or "une", and the word after \t needs to start with [aeiou]
- to be replaced by "\ta" same but [^aeuio]
- to be replaced by "\tthe" needs to match "l'[aeuio]" or "le\s" or "la\s" or "les\s" at the begining of the line.

For the first option, I tried `\t(?=[aeuio][^aeuio]+)(?<=^une|^un)`, discovered that notepad++ doesn't support lookbehinds, and went online to have a PERC engine. Even there, it doesn't match anything.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: In NPP, try `^((?:(une?)|(l(?:'[aeuioh]\w*|a|es?)))\h.*\t\h*)(([aeiou])|((?![aeiou])[a-z]))` and replace with `$1(?{2}(?{6} a $6: an $5):(?{3}the $4))` ([copy from here to test](https://regex101.com/r/TbrAmO/1))

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thanks.

Comment: Please see my answer below with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^((?:(une?)|(l(?:'[aeuioh]\w*|a|es?)))\h.*\t\h*)(([aeiou])|((?![aeiou])[a-z]))
```

and replace with `$1(?{2}(?{6} a $6: an $5):(?{3}the $4))`. **Make sure *`Match Case`* is NOT checked.**

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line
- `(` - start of Group 1:

  - `(?:(une?)|(l(?:'[aeuioh]\w*|a|es?)))` - either of the two alternatives:

    - `(une?)` - Group 2: `un` or `une`
    - `(l(?:'[aeuioh]\w*|a|es?))` - Group 3: `l` followed with `'` and 0+ word chars, or `la` or `le` or `les`
  - `\h` - a horizontal space
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\t` - a TAB char
  - `\h*` -  0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `)` - end of Group 1
- `(([aeiou])|((?![aeiou])[a-z]))` - Group 4 matching two alternatives:

  - `([aeiou])` - Group 5: a vowel
  - `|` - or
  - `((?![aeiou])[a-z])` - Group 6: a consonant (any char but `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`)

**Replacement pattern details**

- `$1` - Insert Group 1 value here
- `(?{2}` - if Group 2 matched

  - `(?{6}` - if Group 6 matched

    - `a $6` - insert space, `a`, space and Group 6 (consonant) value
    - `:` - else
    - `an $5` - insert space, `an`, space and Group 5 (vowel) value
  - `)` - end of the conditional construct
  - `:` - else
  - `(?{3}` - if Group 3 matched

    - `the $4` - insert `the`, space and Group 4 value
  - `)` - end of conditional construct
- `)` - end of conditional construct

Comment: Thanks you soooo much, sensei.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern that works: https://regex101.com/r/burYl1/2

```
^(une?.*\\t)(\s[^aeiou].*)|^(une?.*\\t)(\s[aeiou].*)|^((?:las?|les?).*\\t)(\s.*)
```

However, replacing all three at once can only be done in an environment that supports boosted replace string conditionals (Sublime does not support this). If it were me, I would run this three times matching for each variation.

```
$1 a $2
$3 an $4
$5 the $6
```

If you need the replace conditional, let me know and I'll get it for you.

Comment: So, what are the use of $+ number, is that the groups matched previoulsy ?

Comment: Correct. Every use of plain parentheses will create a new match group that you can reference in your replace string. $1 will refer to the contents of the first pair of parentheses, $2 the second, and so on. Wiktor Stribiżew's answer has a great breakdown of how to create a conditional replace string.